# TypeScript complains «'callee' may not be accessed on strict mode functions» even with alwaysStrict set to false

Tags: typescript, debugging, strict

I'd like to be able to pepper an app with a custom log function when debugging, profiling or just familiarizing myself with the code, using `arguments.callee.name` so I don't have to type the enclosing function by hand, so all I have to do is paste `myProfilingFunc(arguments.callee.name);` anywhere.  It works a treat in JavaScript (without strict mode), but in TypeScript I get:

```
TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
```

even after disabling every strict-related option on tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es2017"
    ],
[...]
    "strict": false,
    "alwaysStrict": false,
    "noImplicitUseStrict": true
  }
}
```

This seems to have worked back in 2019, but not anymore.

Minimal example:

```
function testCallee() {
    console.log(arguments.callee.name);
}

testCallee();
```

[Open in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=false&noImplicitAny=false&strictNullChecks=false&strictFunctionTypes=false&strictPropertyInitialization=false&strictBindCallApply=false&noImplicitThis=false&noImplicitReturns=false&alwaysStrict=false&esModuleInterop=false&jsx=0&module=1&noImplicitUseStrict=true&ts=4.9.3#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygYQIYBtcooAUAlIgN4BQiNiECacBAdLnAOZHYBO7IAtijBQ0zCHgIpmYbIJIBuSgF9KlVBhz5CpeUA)

Comment: `tsc --strict` has nothing to do with the `"use strict"` pragma. It's a shorthand which turns on all of the most rigorous type checks that typescript is capable of. The issue here is that module code is assumed to be strict as it assumed to be es2015 module code, which is strict mode by spec. Set `alwaysStrict` to false.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Aluan, but alwaysStrict is already set to false, as shown in my tsconfig.json, and in the Playground sample, and I still get the error.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are now [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Deprecated_caller_or_arguments_usage).
If what you want is the name of the function stored in the callee do the following:

```js
function testCallee() {
    console.log(testCallee.name);
}

testCallee();
```

As an alternative, you can make use of the Error object and write a function that extracts whatever information you need from it.

```js
function testCallee() {
   const error = new Error();
   const reg = new RegExp(/at\s+((\S+)\s)?\((\S+):(\d+):(\d+)\)/);
   const stact = error.stack?.split('\n').at(1);
   const caller = reg.exec(stact);
   console.log(caller);
}
testCallee();
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I wanted was to paste the same line of code anywhere without modifying it, as I mentioned, with it providing the function name as an argument automatically (for profiling, familiarising myself with the code, etc.).  If I have to type the function name, I might as well do console.log("testCallee"), which is even shorter. :) arguments.callee.name works a treat in JS, but TS wouldn't allow it even after fiddling with the strictness (tho it used to work before).

Comment: You can make use of the `Error` object and write a function that extracts whatever information you need from it.

Comment: Great idea!  It works nicely, except with async functions: https://t.ly/B_JFR, but seems it's as good as it gets, since  callee is still not working.  If you write it as your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the above proposition.